# AirAsia policy on carry-on baggage

Tags: luggage, airports, regulations, philippines

Am I allowed to bring 1.9 g lash glue and tripod in my carry-on baggage? This is only my second time flying and I used to put my tripod in my checked baggage. We didn't get additional baggage this time so I don't know if those items are prohibited in carry-on baggage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AirAsia [states](https://support.airasia.com/s/article/What-items-are-prohibited-en?language=en_GB) :

> > (a) Pointed/edged Weapons & Sharp Objects;
>
> - Axes & hatchets, arrows and darts, crampons (grappling iron, hooked bar of iron, or plate with iron spikes used in mountaineering)
> - Harpoons & spears, ice axes & ice picks, ice skates, lockable or flick knives with blades of any length, knives, including ceremonial,
>   religious and hunting knives made of metal
> - Meat cleavers, machetes, open razors and blades (excluding safety or disposable razors with blades enclosed in cartridge), sabres, swords
>   and swordsticks, scalpels, scissors with blades of any length, ski and
>   walking/hiking poles, throwing stars, tradesman's tools that have the
>   potential to be used as a pointed or edged weapon, e.g. drills and
>   drill bits, box cutters, utility knives, all saws, screwdrivers,
>   crowbars, hammers, pliers, wrenches/spanners, blow torches.
>
> Please take note that any sharp objects in checked-in baggage should
> be securely wrapped to prevent injury to screeners and handling
> personnel
>
> > (b) Blunt Instruments;
>
> - Baseball and softball bats, clubs or batons - rigid or flexible - e.g. billy clubs, blackjacks, night sticks & batons, cricket bats,
>   golf clubs, hockey and hurley sticks, lacrosse sticks;
> - Kayak and canoe paddles, skateboards, billiard, snooker and pool cues, fishing rods;
> - Martial arts equipment, e.g. knuckle dusters, clubs, coshes, rice flails, nun-chucks, kubatons, kubasaunts.
>
> > (c) Batteries (Lithium, Lithium Ion Cells, Batteries, and Spare Batteries)
>
> - Cabin Baggage: Electronics devices such as cameras, cellular phones, laptops, and camcorders containing lithium or lithium ion cells (a Wh
>   rating exceeding 100Wh but not exceeding 160Wh) for personal use are
>   allowed for carriage into the aircraft.
> - Checked Baggage: Portable electronic devices containing lithium metal or lithium ion cells or batteries are allowed in checked baggage
>   EXCEPT e-cigarettes and self-balancing battery powered small vehicles
>   (E.g: Electric Bicycle and Segway).  Spare batteries for example power
>   banks, are NOT allowed in checked baggage. Wheelchairs and mobility
>   devices with batteries can only be carried as checked baggage given
>   that the batteries must be prepared for the flight according to the
>   guide here .
>
> The following items are prohibited in your baggage whether it is
> checked in or not:
>
> > (a) Any Guns, Firearms & Weapons;
>
> [...]
>
> > (b) Explosives and flammable substances;
>
> [...]
>
> > (c) Chemical and toxic substances;
>
> [...]
>
> > (d) Live plants and flowers
>
> [...]

---

Millions of people carry makeup and camera equipment in their carry-on daily, don't worry, you'll have no issue with those items

Comment: Lash glue might be flammable, the OP should check the safety label on the product packaging https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/more_info/?hazmat=3

Comment: So is nail polish, but it's apparently allowed. See https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all . Seems a bit of a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn’t find any information on AirAsia regarding the two items you’re asking, so I checked other airlines. I found “tripod” on Philippine Airlines guidelines and confirm they are allowed on both carry-on and checked baggage. You can check it on this link under “Blunt Instrument” section of the article: https://www.philippineairlines.com/en/before-you-fly/baggage-information/security-reminder. However, the article also cautioned that some countries prohibit these items even in checked baggage. Please check your destination country about their restrictions on the items you’ll be bringing.

Comment: It's usually the origin country, not the destination country, which dictates what can be in cabin or hold luggage or not for security reasons.